# Equation of a circle given the conditions

Tags: geometry

So the problem states that the centre of the circle is in the first quadrant and that circle passes through $x$ axis, $y$ axis and the following line: $3x-4y=12$. I have only one question. The answer denotes $r$ as the radius of the circle and then assumes that centre is at $(r,r)$ because of the fact that the circle passes through $x$ and $y$ axis. I was thinking that this single fact does not permit one to assume that centre must be at $(r,r)$, simply because the centre may be positioned in such a manner that the distance to $y$ and $x$ axis is not the same and not necessarily $r$. Is my thinking correct? If not, why?

Comment: Does it state that the circle passes through the x and y axes or that the x and y axes are tangent to the circle (or maybe touch the circle)?

Comment: "...touches the x and y axes.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given information does specify a unique circle. If however we assume that want the **smallest** possible circle that satisfies the given criteria, then it must be tangent to the $x$-axis and $y$-axis. This guarantees that its center lies on the line $y = x$ so that its centre has the form $(r, r)$.

Answer (score 1):

Given the OP's comment that the circle "touches" the x and y axis, then the center must be at $(r,r)$, though it would have been more correct if the question specified that the circle touched the axes at a single point or that the axes were tangent to the circle. Given that the circle touches the axes at a single point and is in the first quadrant, then the only point that can be the circle's center is $(r,r)$. This follows from the fact that all lines tangent to a circle form a right angle with the line segment from the tangent point to the center (of length $r$).